# Android mapviewballoons

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm using this library https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons in my android app and it is very useful. Now I'm trying to capture the event when you tap the balloon open.  I'd want to launch a new activity after tapping on the text of the balloon open. 
How can I do it?

Thanks at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the demo application of the library. In the [simple](http://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/blob/master/android-mapviewballoons-example/src/mapviewballoons/example/simple/SimpleItemizedOverlay.java) example, replace

```
@Override
protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(c, "onBalloonTap for overlay index " + index,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

with

```
@Override
protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
    // start your Activity here
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Mh and do I have to set it in the class in which I use the ItemizedOverlay objects?

Comment: no, just in the class that extends BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>. try out the simple example, you can copy the code into your own application.

Comment: I just tried to do this but there is a problem. I can't launch a new activity from that class. =(

Comment: why not? what is the error message? try this code in onBalloonTap: `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class));`

Comment: This is the error "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type MyItemizedOverlay" and this is my code:

 @Override
 protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {  
  Intent to_taghelp = new Intent(c, HelpTagActivity.class); 
  
  to_taghelp.putExtra("TagList", item.getSnippet());
  
  startActivity(to_taghelp);
  
     return true;
 }

Comment: i think i know what the problem is. two solutions: #1 declare the MyItemizedOverlay class inside the other class where you use the ItemizedOverlays. #2 hand over a reference to the activity to the ItemizedOverlay class, similar as you do it with the context

Comment: I solved it! 

 @Override
 protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
  
  Intent to_taghelp = new Intent(c, HelpTagActivity.class); 
  to_taghelp.putExtra("TagList", item.getSnippet());
  c.startActivity(to_taghelp);
  
     return true;
 }

Answer (score 1):

You are missing context infront of startActivity() method

```
c.startActivity(to_taghelp);
```